# Cordova doesn’t work redirecting URL to outside server

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, android-camera, cordova-plugins

I am trying to make and app in Android that lets you complete a checklist form and at the same time, lets you take some pictures with the camera. I installed the latest version of Cordova, the Java JDK, the Android SDK, Apache ANT, NodeJS, etc.

I want that the app to load an external URL using “super.loadUrl()”.

My problem is that while running the HTML code in `loadUrl(launchUrl)`, it works properly and the camera gets activated, going outside URL, it doesn’t even [*what do you mean here?*] I copied all files that are in `platforms\android\assets\www` to the server, also “cordova.js”.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Include this in your config.xml
`<access origin="*"/>`

Answer (score 0):

May be a restriction you need to ease.
See [access origin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide/appdev/whitelist/).

Answer (score 0):

This is my config.xml. "access origin" seams to be ok. Morevoer the app open de out html but when I want to take picture, it makes nothing:

```
<widget id="net.techniksoft3.app" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG" />
    <feature name="Whitelist">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.whitelist.WhitelistPlugin" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Camera">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.camera.CameraLauncher" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="File">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Media">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.media.AudioHandler" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Capture">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.mediacapture.Capture" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="FileTransfer">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.filetransfer.FileTransfer" />
    </feature>
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    <name>TechnikSoft</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
</widget>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. this part was missing in config.xml

```
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" launch-external="yes" />
<allow-navigation href="https://*/*" launch-external="yes" />
<allow-navigation href="data:*" launch-external="yes" />
```

Thanks a lot for your help.